# Validação com Parsley e janela Modal

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Estou com um problema e não consigo resolver.
Tenho um botão que quando clica sobre ele apresenta uma mensagem para o usuário de confirmação, acontece que antes de abrir esse modal eu gostaria de validar se todos os campos estão preenchidos.

Para validação estou usando a lib **Parsley**

Se eu apenas usar o botão simples conforme abaixo a validação é feita com sucesso.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
```

Porém se usar o botão que chama o modal não consigo usar o validator antes.

```
<button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#md-default" type="button" id="postar" class="btn btn-info btn-lg"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> <b>Enviar</b></button>


     <!-- Modal -->
                              <div class="modal fade" id="md-default" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
                                 <div class="modal-dialog">
                                    <div class="modal-content">
                                       <div class="modal-header">
                                          <button type="button " class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                                       </div>
                                       <div class="modal-body">
                                          <div class="text-center">
                                             <div class="i-circle primary"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></div>
                                             <div class="confirmacao" id="confirmacao">
                                                <h4>Confirma o envio do Push?</h4>
                                             </div>
                                             <div class="resp"></div>
                                             <p></p>
                                          </div>
                                       </div>
                                       <div class="modal-footer">
                                          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-flat" data-dismiss="modal" id="cancelButton" >Cancelar</button>
                                          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-flat enviar" id="submitButton" >Sim</button>
                                          <button type="button" style="display: none" class="btn btn-default btn-flat" data-dismiss="modal" id = "closeButton">Fechar</button>
                                       </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- /.modal-content -->
                                 </div>
                                 <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
                              </div>


    <!-- /.modal -->
```

Comment: coloque seu código javascript também.

Comment: não tem código javascript somente uso a no input "required".

  <script src="js/jquery.parsley/dist/parsley.js" </script>
  <script src="js/jquery.parsley/dist/i18n/pt-br.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
  window.ParsleyValidator.setLocale('pt-br');
      $('form').parsley();
    });
  </script>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro você vai precisar criar um arquivo `javascript` para validar seu form com o `Parsley`, logo após, você vai ter que usar o próprio `Parsley` para verificar se o form foi validado com sucesso ou não.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var form = $("#form").parsley();
if (form.isValid()) {
    $("#myModal").modal("show");
   }
});
```